# '[[ 1' -gt 0 ']]' command not found, no special character shown by set -x

Tags: bash, while-loop

When writing a bash script with command line arguments, I use the following structure :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

extension=".fna.gz"
declare -A genomes_completeness
declare -a genomes
declare -a completeness


Help() {
echo "help message"
}

#set default values of variables and declare types
foo=bar

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        Help
        exit
fi

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
        case $1 in
        -f | --foo) foo="$2"
        shift 2;;
        -b | --bar) bar="$2"
        shift 2;;
        -h | --help) Help; exit;;
        -* | --*) unknown="$1"; echo -e "Unknown option: ${unknown}"; Help; exit 1;;
        *) shift;;
        esac
done
```

It works well and I was writing another one but stumbled upon this error when checking if the Help message was correctly showing up when executing the script with no argument or the `help` flag:

```bash
bash /path/script.sh --help

+ extension=.fna.gz
+ declare -A genomes_completeness
+ declare -a genomes
+ declare -a completeness
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ '[[ 1' -gt 0 ']]'
/path/script.sh: line 28: [[ 1: command not found
```

After looking for an error for a while (hoho) I just copy-pasted the `while ...` (that line only) of another script and it then worked.

I wrote the script entirely by hand on linux with nano, so I have no idea if I inserted a special character (and how). If there was a special character would it show with `set -x` ? What are the other possible sources of that error ?

I hope the question is asked correctly.

Comment: That's not the output I get from that script. `extension` and  `genomes_completeness` etc. do not even exist in the script so, you are not running the script you pasted here.

Comment: `'[[ 1'` in the debug output indicates that your `[[` and `$#` are being treated as a single token. That should not happen in a standard environment. Is this really the entire script you're running to get that?

Comment: For troubleshooting you could try deleting and re-adding the whitespace in between `[[` and `$#` in a different editor.

Comment: @tjm3772 Just copying the whole script as it was pasted here would work too. It runs without errors.

Comment: @tjm3772 no I summerised it. I understood what was failing (your explenation) but not what could be the root cause. I will edit and add missing code so you can have the same output.

Comment: Your new code still runs without giving the output you claim to get. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didnt include this code because it was not relevant but I edited the code to add it. The error happens before any argument is used of read.

Comment: @Yama No, no error happens neither if I give it no arguments nor `--help`.

Comment: It looks like a non-breaking space got into there. What editor do you use?

Comment: We need code that is _tested_ to cause your output exactly as given in the question. Consider using a sandbox like https://repl.it/ or https://ideone.com/ for the purpose.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I indeed corrected the error. My question is not "how to solve this" but "why could have caused this", as written at the end of the post. Maybe it wasnt clear.

Comment: Then the prior "a non-breaking space" is your answer. But speculation about "could" is questionably topical; pasting a lookalike character is a typo, and questions caused by typos are off-topic.

Comment: @glennjackman nano

Comment: BTW, think about using `cat -A yourscript` to print the script's content in a way that makes invisible characters visible and distinguishable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the advice ! I did not cat indeed, thought I wrote something wrong. FIrst time I face that sort of issue. Didnt think I could insert a weird character easely with nano.

Comment: Hm. I'm a little disappointed to see that in practice, `LC_ALL=C` isn't enough to make the non-breaking space be escaped explicitly. (Testing with `(set -x; nbsp=$'\u00a0'; eval "[[${nbsp}hello ]]")`)

Comment: ...but `LC_ALL=C` _does_ result in a better error message, even though it doesn't improve the xtrace output; `bash: $'[[\302\240hello': command not found` is a lot more useful than `bash: [[ hello: command not found`

Comment: Make sure you disable all "smart" conversions when editing programs. It's best to use an IDE rather than a word processor, they're designed for text.

Comment: Have a look at your script with a hex editor. I bet that the character after the `[[` is not a 20 (space) character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> may insert a non-breaking space character. Commonly, the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key is mapped to be "Compose".

Some systems also insert a non-breaking space if you type <kbd>Shift + Space</kbd>

On linux, `setxkbmap -print` may show configuration and `man 7 xkeyboard-config` has information about configuring non-breaking space input.

Comment: I figured it must have been the `shift`+`space` because I do need `shift` to get the `#$` that comes after the space. Marked as the answer as it is the most likely to happen.